# couldn't get interactive broker historical data

Tags: interactive-brokers

I am working on IB Gateway and want to get the historical data.
As i have completed the steps on IB Gateway software to enable the API.

I am using python notebook for this.
For now i am running this code and i am able to import the given library but rest of the code giving me this error. Important thing is connection is established as I have mention client id 1. then it is created and can be seen on IB Gateway application.

My code is here.

```
from ib_insync import *
#util.startLoop() # uncomment this line when in a notebook

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 5021, clientId=1)

bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
       contract=Stock('TSLA', 'SMART', 'USD'),
       endDateTime='',
       durationStr='30 D',
       barSizeSetting='1 hour',
       whatToShow='TRADES',
       useRTH=True)

print(bars)
```

Here is the error.

```
Peer closed connection
clientId 1 already in use?
API connection failed: CancelledError()
```

As i am using notebook if i uncomment the second line (util.startLoop()) `it adds one more error about timeout..`

Need help to get this done.

Big Thanks

Comment: What is the actual error from IB if there is any? Are you sure you are subscribed to data and are not running parallel accounts? If you run a production account with live data and a demo account for testing with only one data subscription, you will not get data on the latter.

Comment: You can only connect with a unique clientId.  Change it in case you're already connected.  There have been cases where the disconnect doesn't work or takes a long time so just change the clientId.  I don't use ib_insync but there is a user group by the author here https://groups.io/g/insync

Answer (score 0):

Assign a different `clientID` to this connecion:

```
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 5021, clientId=2)
```

Apparently you already have another connection with `clientId=1`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, helped build the connection.